# Adverb followed by って

Tags: grammar, て-form, i-adjectives, gemination, particle-って

> おいらなんて、怒られっぱなしの人生だもんねーー。アハハ。でもおもしろくって仕方ないもんねー。
>
> For me, it's the life of being got angry at. Ha Ha. But, interesting(ly)...it can't be helped ??

I'm guessing this is おもしろく (interestingly) with either って=は or って=と.
I've never seen an adverb used as a topic before, but it doesn't really seem to work as a quote marker either. Can anyone shed some light here? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard form is おもしろくて仕方ない, where おもしろくて is used as an adjective (not adverb) in the [て-form for connecting predicates](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3439/%E3%81%84adjective-difference-between-%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A6-and-%E3%81%8F).

> (て-form adjective) + 仕方ない

or

> (たい-form verb in て-form) + 仕方ない

is a common phrase that means “It's so (adjective)” or “I really want to (verb)”. The nuance of this 仕方ない is “I can't stand it”, but it's not to be taken literally, just like when someone says “My homework is so hard it's *killing me*”.

#### Examples

- 眠くて{ねむくて}仕方ない *I'm so sleepy*
- 彼女はかわいくて仕方ない *She's so cute*
- 不思議{ふしぎ}で仕方ない *It's so strange*
- 虫がうるさくて仕方ない *The bugs are so noisy*
- 帰りたくて仕方ない *I really want to go home*

The `っ` can be inserted in the `くて` for emphatic effect: かわいくて→かわいくって, うるさくて→うるさくって, etc.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably a grammatical error.
It's supposed to be おもしろくて but this person added the っ in before the て, because of a simple grammatical error, or to make an emphatic connotation, like "it's soooo interesting".

Comment: Good thinking in terms of grammar.  Believe it or not, it's acceptable. small つ is often used in speaking as an emphasis.

Comment: As a way to represent spoke language yes, but even then it is still a grammatical error in a strict sense.
A lost of the Japanese spoken language is full of what would be formally be considered as grammatical errors, that's one of the reasons automatic translators have such a hard time trying to decipher it's meaning.

Comment: Very interesting to hear that the use of 促音 is always a grammatical error.  You should cite the souce to back up your statement.