# Past tense verb followed by って仕方ない

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language, i-adjectives, particle-って

Girl A is complaining about her bleak future to girl B. Girl B replies:

> 泣いたって仕方ないじゃん。

I asked a similar question [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28999/adverb-followed-by-%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6) about おもしろくって仕方ない where I was told that it was a more emphatic version of おもしろくて仕方ない

I'm struggling to apply similar thinking to this construction.

Is って short for という in this case?

I don't know how to translate this sentence at all (note that there is no suggestion that the girl was crying before this sentence).

> I can't stand that you cried, can I?
>   It's no use that you cried is it?

Neither of these attempts sounds right. Please help.

Comment: 「泣いたって」の「たって」はこれ→[デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/137398/meaning/m0u/)　(≒「泣いても」)

Comment: See [How to parse ～なくたって](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19593) and [Tanaka corpus examples for 〜たって](http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?1Q%A4%BF%A4%C3%A4%C6_0__)

Comment: "Even if you cry, it doesn't help, does it?"?