# Proper translation for 忘れやすく動きに時間がかかる

Tags: grammar, translation, adjectives, adverbs

I am trying to translate the following.

> 頭で覚えたことは、忘れやすく動きに時間がかかるという特徴があります。

The part that confuses me is

> 忘れやすく動きに時間がかかる

If 動き means "activity" then 動きに時間がかかる means roughly "it takes time for activity".

Next, 忘れやすく is an adverb that is from an adjective 忘れやすい. So
忘れやすく must modify the verb かかる rather than the noun 動き.

If 忘れやすい is used instead of 忘れやすく, it modifies the noun 動き.

It is hard to translate

> 頭で覚えたことは、忘れやすく動きに時間がかかるという特徴があります。

properly. My attempt is as follow.

> The characteristic of remembering by thinking is that the activity takes time with easily to forget manner.

Could you help me to translate it properly?

Comment: I don't think it's adverbial. "Easy to forget **and** takes time to work". Someone more competent than me should confirm though. See this link: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3439/%e3%81%84adjective-difference-between-%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a6-and-%e3%81%8f

Comment: @user3856370 I am not any more competent than you, but I do know you are  spot on that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 「頭{あたま}で覚{おぼ}えたことは、忘{わす}れやすく動{うご}きに時間{じかん}がかかるという特徴{とくちょう}があります。」

＝

> 「頭で覚えたことは、忘れやすく、動きに時間がかかるという特徴があります。」

The basic structure of this sentence is:

> 頭で覚えたこと has two characteristics.  #1 is 忘れやすい and #2, 動きに時間がかかる.

Judging from your comments and final translation, you did not grasp this structure correctly.

> Next, 忘れやすく is an adverb that is from an adjective 忘れやすい. So 忘れやすく must modify the verb かかる rather than the noun 動き.

No and no, I am afraid.  This misunderstanding cost you all the way, it seems.  「忘れやす**く**」 is not an adverb; It is an ***adjective***.  More specifically, it is the 連用形{れんようけい} (continuative form) of the adjective 「忘れやす**い**」.

Thus, I used a comma above after 「忘れやすく」, hoping it might help you see the sentence structure better.  「忘れやすく」 here, does ***not*** modify either 「かかる」 or 「動き」.  It is pretty "independent" in meaning in this sentence.  It is one of the two characteristics that I speak of and it is in the 連用形 because the writer must go on to talk about the other characteristic.

One TL attempt by me would be:

> "The things you learn in your head have (two) characteristics -- 1) they are easy to forget and 2) it takes much time for you to put them to work (in the real world).

You may call this speculation, but I think it is saying that it would be "better" to learn things with your body rather than with your brain.

Comment: +1 The continuative form of 忘れやすい is 忘れやすくて, I think. How can it become 忘れやすく?

Comment: ^ The continuative form (連用形) of ～やすい is ～やすく, and て is a conjunctive particle(接続助詞), so I think ～やすくて is the て-form.