# Question about the part "のどは針のように細く" of this phrase

Tags: grammar, words

I found this in 大辞林 for ガキ:

I know that the appropriate definition is probably:

> 俗に，子供の意。
> In slang, has the meaning of kid

But I always love to read the definitions with the (仏) in them:

> 〔仏〕（ア）生前の悪業の報いで，餓鬼道に落ちた亡者(モウジヤ)。体はやせ細り，**のどは針のように細く**，また，手にとった食物が火に変わってしまうため常に飢えに苦しんでいるとされる。（イ）「餓鬼道」の略。

I have a bit of problems with this part (in bold). Firstly the meaning of 針のよう (appearance/feeling of a needle?). And also 細い which is in adverb form 細く - what verb is it modifying here?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3439/%e3%81%84adjective-difference-between-%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a6-and-%e3%81%8f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly too long for a comment.

You're interpreting のよう too literally. Xのように is a common grammar construct. It is an adverbial phrase that means "like X". So のどは針のように細く means "the throat is thin like a needle".

On the other hand 細く is not adverbial. Please see the link I added to your question for an explanation  of that.